# Storage layout key-value pair generation for pre-deployment of smart contract

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain

Could anybody please let me know how do we generate key-value pair for smart contract pre-deployment purpose.
I knows about the storage slot and its value assignment but I would like to know how to generate key-value pair for representing relationship of mapping?

Here is an example for storage initialization key-value pair

"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004",
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002": "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000004860d8812f0b38878000000",
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004",

```
    "0x290decd9548b62a8d60345a988386fc84ba6bc95484008f6362f93160ef3e563": "0x0000000000000000000000009967CC16374F0d20551a0da82486008fEE453332",
    "0x290decd9548b62a8d60345a988386fc84ba6bc95484008f6362f93160ef3e564": "0x00000000000000000000000085318b9FBe5C878075fd41Cefb099b9e7efD92C3",
    "0x290decd9548b62a8d60345a988386fc84ba6bc95484008f6362f93160ef3e565": "0x0000000000000000000000004dfA170b1F0dF4F208d1cf2B0b995b4877C089af",
    "0x290decd9548b62a8d60345a988386fc84ba6bc95484008f6362f93160ef3e566": "0x000000000000000000000000f81d8516d4d7000b98ff305a1599f0ea265833b5",

    "0x318c8b225573fc23ea888f9d5b49b79fb4bae88708861a35df184596cc1f4696": "0x000000000000000000000000c15041ef7ccd408b733b78684fcacc979f0dcb9b",
    "0x4b3210d5ec6857a7dc6e8a2fd1649fd0cb5e59c569863e0dba312aff31386deb": "0x0000000000000000000000003bab0a4ced37c1d585fc61d81a05ba1e7bb1b7a1",
    "0xe4f026e7475df3aec17bfe2ed046170b82d051b6e6ff65d3bd12e8a1b84748f3": "0x00000000000000000000000013dc89380bb99c8418c31df30a76f4654b23bcd2",
    "0x7c9f6fed313b4cce3eaa26dacbe9fe9c35c8d476c1117091ffdc2a6824463f29": "0x000000000000000000000000f5d42c02fcbc1caa864f81c1ed0dbc40fc220493",

    "0xc03a82001cb5d5c18e0221ae00c89c47c21950c9fe32c159505c64f3e97cc344": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000019d971e4fe8401e74000000",
    "0x7cfbc4d1b8dcdd160089d129720ea48553480f691bdeef58d91aa8dececb69af": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000019d971e4fe8401e74000000",
    "0x3482c46e4180ac93167854f7ed195c5066979001d6f568021ebe3178657c7b4f": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000019d971e4fe8401e74000000",
    "0xc471bb5e9976b4af9edd656c431079ed4bdce9244ad89256356b110bba96a4ee": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000019d971e4fe8401e74000000"
```

And these pairs represent the relationship :

validator 0x9967CC16374F0d20551a0da82486008fEE453332 depositor 0xC15041Ef7ccd408B733b78684FcaCc979F0dCb9B depositAmount 500000000000000000000000000
validator 0x85318b9FBe5C878075fd41Cefb099b9e7efD92C3 depositor 0x3BaB0A4CED37C1d585fC61D81a05ba1E7bb1b7a1 depositAmount 500000000000000000000000000
validator 0x4dfA170b1F0dF4F208d1cf2B0b995b4877C089af depositor 0x13dC89380bB99C8418c31dF30a76F4654B23BcD2 depositAmount 500000000000000000000000000
validator 0xF81D8516d4d7000B98FF305a1599F0Ea265833b5 depositor 0xF5d42C02FcBc1CaA864F81c1Ed0DBc40FC220493 depositAmount 500000000000000000000000000